# Ckeditor 5 how to append text at the end of the content

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x

I want to append text to my Ckeditor after opening a model.

So the situation is, I open my model, I receive some data with an ajax call. The data I receive I want to append to my ckeditor.

So far I have tried this:

```
rememberEditorInvoiceMailing[0].model.change( writer => {
    const insertPosition = rememberEditorInvoiceMailing[0].model.document.selection.getFirstPosition();
    writer.insertText( 'foo', insertPosition, 'after' );
});
```

But this inserts text at the beginning of the content.

I also tried this, with ranges:

```
rememberEditorInvoiceMailing[0].model.change( writer => {
    let targetEditor = writer,
        range = targetEditor.createRange();

    range.moveToElementEditEnd(range.root);
    targetEditor.insertText("<p>foo</p>", 'html', range);
});
```

But this gives me the error

> Uncaught CKEditorError: model-createpositionat-offset-required

Any one knows how to approach this?